# I have a 1994 Chevrolet Silverado K15. I replaced the entire cooling system but I had a blown head gasket. It's overheating while driving

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, silverado

My question is. I replaced the cooling system completely. Had blown head gasket. Used blue devil didn't work. Flushed system used bars leak worked but its only overheating while driving. Loosing most of the fluid. New thermostat. Would a clogged radiator cause the problem. Too much pressure. Heater core is fine , water pump fine. Sensors fine, new hoses. It's a 1994 Chevy Silverado K15 with a 5.7 engine. Engine runs like a champ.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Where are you losing the fluid? Is the issue the head gasket?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with those older models they get a lot of slag and rust build up especially depending on how deteriorated the water pump sorry the older water pump was in and how many fence it lost what could happen is somewhere in the block it could get a clog and cause it to overheat and it is specific area sometimes your best bet is to do a radiator flush or cooling system flush or remove the water pump and actually do a complete block flush there are chemicals or additives that you get from either advance Auto parts or online you just want to be careful that they're not too corrosive on an older block because they have Steelheads and it could either way at the head gasket or more of the block than you wanted to before unclogging whatever may be inside the block if that is your issue